# Can i use the instagram api to gather data on what people search and like?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

Is it possible to use the API to find out what a user likes the most and what hahtag they search the most? If not is it possible to use the API to gather information in general on what is the most liked picture and most searched hashtag?

Comment: Did you actually look up the API docs? Yes, there are endpoints for retrieving most popular posts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently there is no API to get most liked or most searched hashtag